# Sequelize Postgres - How can i build One-to-many relationship between two models

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, one-to-many

I have defined the two models `category` and `sub-category`, and I have quite a confusion to build the relationship b/w the two models, how can I do that? here category has many sub-category and sub-category belongs to a category.

category model

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { getConnection } = require("../helper/databaseConnection");

const categoryModel = {
  category_id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
  category_name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
};

let category = null;
const initCategoryModel = async () => {
  try {
    if (category) return category;
    const sequelize = await getConnection();
    category = sequelize.define("category", categoryModel, {
      freezeTableName: true,
    });

   await category.sync({ alter: true });    
    return category;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("category", err);
  }
};

module.exports = { initCategoryModel };
```

sub-category model

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { getConnection } = require("../helper/databaseConnection");

const subcatModel = {
  subcat_id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
  subcat_name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
};

let subcat = null;
const initSubcatModel = async () => {
  try {
    if (subcat) return subcat;
    const sequelize = await getConnection();
    subcat = sequelize.define("sub_category", subcatModel, {
      freezeTableName: true,
    });

    await subcat.sync({ alter: true });
    return subcat;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("sub category", err);
  }
};

module.exports = { initSubcatModel };
```

Comment: Did you look at the Associations section in the official Sequelize documentation?

Comment: Yup! By referring to the docs, I did it in my own way!

Comment: I don't see any defined associations in the your code